# Is there an app on Linux similar to superputty on Windows?

Tags: linux, ssh

superputty manages multiple SSH connections, in a nutshell.

I'd be needing to connect to several AWS EC2 instances and putty works fine with the keys, but it's just one at a time. I also tried Remmina, however it keeps asking SSH private keyphrase that it shouldn't. Any other suggestion?

Comment: As for the Remmina issue: ever tried `ssh-agent` in this context? AFAIR this tool caches your key/password when used for the first time.

Comment: Can you explain a little more of what superputty does? You can SSH to multiple servers at once on Linux; in fact, because some GUI terminal emulators on Linux have tabs, you can use multiple tabs. If you want to be able to type the same command to multiple servers, tmux can help with that, although you may be better off with a configuration management system like Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

The ssh client handles this type of thing automagically on Linux.

Look in ~/.ssh -

```
user@darkstar ~/.ssh $ ls -l
total 60
-rw------- 1 user user  1692 Jun 24  2013 amazonkey.pem
-rw------- 1 user user  1696 Jul 11  2013 clark-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   393 Nov 23 18:47 config
-rw------- 1 user user  1675 Feb 29  2016 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   393 Feb 29  2016 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 user user 19690 Dec 19 20:02 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 user user 19246 Dec 11 23:59 known_hosts.old
user@darkstar ~/.ssh $
```

You have your various keys (the 2 .pem files are from aws, the id_rsa is my own private key) and the config file, as well as the known_hosts.

The config file is where your magic happens

```
Host amazoninstance
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/amazonkey.pem
    HostName my.domain.name.at.amazon.com
    User someusername
    Port 2223
```

With that, all I do is

```
user@darkstar ~/ $ ssh amazoninstance
```

And it connects as specified in the config file, and provides the identity key automatically.  And I'm logged in Just Like That.  Need to connect to multiple servers at once?  Start a screen session, or open other X terms, or new tabs in your X term client if it supports it, etc.

Note that SOME desktop environments on SOME distributions will want you to create a local keystore and password protect access to the keys in your ~/.ssh and such...

Answer (score 0):

1. Explaining what is superputty and what it does other than putty for example would help.
2. If Remina does the job for you, why don't you resolve the problem with private key than searching another tool?
3. SuperPuTTy [runs on Linux](https://github.com/jimradford/superputty/wiki/Documentation).

Comment: #1 It manages multiple ssh connections, in a nutshell. 

Is it customary, that I should provide a functional description of an existing piece of software what I ask for an alternative here?

#2 It does not seem to do the job. And I did not set up a private passphrase, nor do I want to. All other access methods work fine. (Command line ssh, putty)

#3 It doesn't. Your reference point to the following:
System Requirements

- A PC running Windows (XP, Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10)
- Running under Linux with Mono and or Wine is not supported due to the Windows proprietary

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh: Re. #1: Yes. Always assume that answerers don’t know the software. It is also typically the case that you don’t need *all* of the features the software offers. So please always describe what kind of software you need and list which features it must have.